# JavaScript clicking letter displays text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have something of an easter egg in my website. If you click the letter f in the word food, a picture of brownies appears. I can click the letter f and the brownies appear, but the issue is that the word food does not appear as one word it appears with a break between f and ood.

I have a JSfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/od88txko/

My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.f').on('click', function () {
        $('div', this).text(function (text) {
            return text === 'f' ? 'f' : 'f';
        }).parent().next().toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<span class="f">f</span>ood
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/od88txko/2/)** (I also edited your JS to reflect the HTML change)

Ok so as noted in other responses that's because `<div>` is a block level element.  [As explained by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) (bold added for emphasis):

> "Block-level" is categorization of HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) elements, as contrasted with "inline" elements. Block-level elements may appear only within a  element. Their most significant characteristic is that **they typically are formatted with a line break before and after the element (thereby creating a stand-alone block of content)**. That is, they take up the width of their containers.

Comment: Please explain why a span should be used here. Answers should teach, not give!

Comment: But @Daniel_Sanchez already did :)...also Thad Blankenship did too!

Comment: Thanks! I had not thought about this. I thought there was something wrong with my jquery. lol

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are using a `div`, which is a block element. You want an `inline` element, such as `span`

Comment: Also update the jQuery selector to look for a `span` rather than a `div`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because a DIV is a block-level element. try using SPAN instead